# Audit rows deleted using SSMS GUI?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I found the following query from [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4269/how-to-find-out-who-deleted-some-data-sql-server) which appears to show row deletions from a specific table:

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname
SET @TableName = 'dbo.ObjectInstances'

SELECT
    u.[name] AS UserName
    , l.[Begin Time] AS TransactionStartTime
FROM
    fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) l
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        [Transaction ID]
    FROM 
        fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) 
    WHERE
        AllocUnitName LIKE @TableName + '%'
    AND
        Operation = 'LOP_DELETE_ROWS'
    ) deletes
ON  deletes.[Transaction ID] = l.[Transaction ID]
INNER JOIN
    sysusers u
ON  u.[sid] = l.[Transaction SID]
```

The results all show the same username, which is the username we use from our app to connect to the database. However, I had *just* deleted a row using SSMS, while logged in using Windows Authentication.  This record is not shown in the results from the query above.

How can I view an audit of rows/records deleted using SSMS (right-click, delete)?

Comment: Did you delete a row using a DELETE command in a query window (and are you sure you didn't start a transaction and it's still open), or did you use the Edit N Rows UI (in which case perhaps the changes haven't yet committed)? Are you _sure_ the window you're using is using Windows auth? What does `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT, SUSER_SNAME();` say?

Comment: Yes, I used "Edit Top 200 Rows" and then right-click > delete. I'm sure I'm using windows auth... your query shows my machinename\accountname.

Comment: Sorry, the post didn't clarify Edit Top 200 Rows, so I wanted to be sure I understand what you meant (and there are two different ways to `right-click, delete` just in that one dialog). But also [see this](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-the-visual-designers) - Edit Top 200 Rows is a pretty reckless way to modify data IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you should use `sys.database_principals` instead of `sysusers`, which was deprecated in 2005 (just look at [the big warning in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysusers-transact-sql)). But in this case, you can do this without joining to anything - `SUSER_SNAME()` against the sid retrieved the Windows username for me both writing a proper `DELETE` query and also when using the GUI as a crutch:

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname = N'dbo.ObjectInstances';

SELECT UserName = SUSER_SNAME(l.[Transaction SID]), l.[Begin Time]
FROM sys.fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) AS l
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT [Transaction ID]
    FROM sys.fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) 
    WHERE AllocUnitName LIKE @TableName + N'%'
    AND Operation = N'LOP_DELETE_ROWS'
) AS deletes
ON  deletes.[Transaction ID] = l.[Transaction ID]
AND l.Operation = N'LOP_BEGIN_XACT';
```

You may also want to consider joining a 3rd time to be sure the sequence was finalized with a `LOP_COMMIT_XACT` (in other words, maybe you don't need to audit transactions that are still active or were rolled back, and this would also give you a better idea of when the change was actually committed vs. when they started thinking about making a change).

And just as an aside:

- [Ladies and gentlemen, start your semi-colons!](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)

Comment: This did produce additional rows that look more like I expected, unfortunately the UserName is NULL.  Ideas?

Comment: @Devil'sAdvocate Is it possible you are gaining access via a group and not your Windows username?

Comment: Damn.  Entirely possible since I just went through the process of setting that up a few days ago (which was a pain).  But I didn't want to have to add all the developers individually.  So that screwed my auditing?

Comment: I'm sure there is a solution, but you may have to hunt and peck for it. Take the `[Transaction SID]` from the `LOP_BEGIN_XACT` row and look for that sid in `sys.server_principals` and `sys.database_principals`. I will try to repro but my dev environment is local Docker containers on a Mac so it isn't very easy to simulate your scenario. Keep in mind that if you allow a developer in via a group, in a lot of scenarios you effectively audit the group, not each individual member.

Comment: I appreciate the help and advice. Since your solution did work for my test table as expected, I have marked it as accepted.

Comment: Side question: What does the `N` do in your declare statement?

Comment: There may be exceptions, but almost all metadata in SQL Server is Unicode. The `N` prefix makes sure that if you have Unicode characters, they're not lost in translation, so it's just a good habit to always use it when the type is `nchar`/`nvarchar`. To see what happens when you leave it out, compare: `SELECT WithNPrefix = N'我', WithoutNPrefix = '我';` but also see [this post](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/04/t-sql-queries/implicit-conversion-costs) for potential performance impact if you apply the `N` prefix when comparing to a `char`/`varchar` column.